# how to return an excel sheet and a string response using httpresponse Django Python

Tags: python, django, excel, httpresponse

I am currently returning a response page as a string but I also want to pass it as an excel file. I am having trouble doing both.

This is my views.py file:

```
response = HttpResponse(htmlString)
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=example1.xls'
book.save(response)    

return response
```

This only gives me the excel file and not the HtmlString which is because I am reassigning response but I dont know how to include both paramaters.

THanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP response (as in the HTTP protocol, this is not limited to Django) will be treated by the browser either as a file, or displayed in the browser (html, plain text, etc). You cannot return a response with both.

Comment: Is there any way to include a button or something so that I can do both. @goncalopp

Comment: @Santiago You can return a webpage with your string and a link (anchor) to the file (located at another url), it that's what you mean. You can also use a form button for that, sure. If you're talking about making a button open two new pages, you can do that using javascript (search for it). You can't open both on the same page though, AFAIK